# Whats wrong with my JSON file? or what do i need to do? VS Code LIVE SERVER works ONLY on my Windows and not on my iMac

Tags: html, css, json, visual-studio-code

I uninstalled/installed Live server, updated the files from GitHub ritwickdey, and updated the JSON file as mentioned on freecodecamp (asked to add chrome to live server) but it still doesn't work on iMac running high sierra.
I have to turn off live server then load it again to launch an HTML file to see any updates made. I can see the updates in real-time on my windows laptop but won work on the mac

updated live server file from GitHub ritwickdey
updated live server JSON file below:

```
    "editor.wordWrap": "on",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "liveshare.presence": false,
    "explorer.confirmDragAndDrop": false,
    "terminal.explorerKind": "external",
    "workbench.startupEditor": "newUntitledFile",
    "editor.hover.enabled": false,
    "liveSassCompile.settings.excludeList": [

        "**/node_modules/**",
        ".vscode/**"
    ],
    "liveSassCompile.settings.autoprefix": [],
    "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
    "liveServer.settings.donotVerifyTags": true,
    "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
    "vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection": "automaticallyOverrodeDefaultValue",
    "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
    "[css]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "liveServer.settings.root": "",
    "liveServer.settings.CustomBrowser": "chrome",
    "liveServer.settings.AdvanceCustomBrowserCmdLine": ""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I went back, and after heavy messing around with VScode, on Mac:  when you right click on the .html file you have the option of OPEN CHANGES WITH REVISION. I selected that and my .html files are working as they are supposed to. Now I can see my updates in real time